# Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and redirects?

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, webbrowser-control

I've been working on a small console application (c#) for fetching a series of csv files. I have an URL and some POST data and I'm using the WebBrowser component due to javascript embedded in some of the pages. I've run into a little problem (been debugging for 2 days now) where the webbrowser control does not redirect as specified by one of the responses (302). See screen shot (request in red box, should redirect but doesn't):
[image]
Since the last request being sent is a POST with a bunch of data created by javascript and it doesn't seem to be possible to extract the post data from the webbrowser, I cannot intercept the request and just use HttpWebRequest instead. I have also tried looking at other web browser components such as GeckoFX and WebKit.net, but none seem to work.
I could really use some input here, since I'm pretty much stuck.

***Update: Added new image to point to request not redirecting correctly. Request nr. 8 (wrong scenario) is the same as request nr. 6 (right scenario)

Comment: A little difficult to follow as both images appear to show different processes (hops don't match)  How do you know it is not redirecting?  Can you indicate on both images which one should be redirecting that isn't?

Comment: I've updated the picture. In the wrong scenario, as soon as it hits the last request, I get the Navigating event, but not the DocumentCompleted or Nagivated event. And Fiddler shows nothing after this request, so I'm pretty sure the redirect doesn't occur.

Comment: and if you access that page in a standard browser does it actually redirect?

Comment: Yes, the scenario that works, is by using Firefox (and I presume any other real browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the HttpWebRequest object instead, since it lets you disable automatical redirecting. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error - page was not finished loading. However the WebBrowser control still doesn't fire the Navigating and Navigated events when executing a 302 redirect.

Comment: They shouldn't fire on a 302 redirect but if memory serves there is an accept redirect or something like that sadly on the mobile so can't check

Comment: Couldn't find anything on the WebBrowser control, allowing me to configure redirects. However on the HttpWebRequest there's a AllowAutoRedirect property. When set to false, it doesn't automatically redirect and let's you handle it your self.